# How to calculate row medians efficiently with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a fairly large data.table (15M rows, 15 columns) for which I want to calculate the median of each row. I can do this using

```
apply(DT, 1, median)  # DT is my data.table
```

but this is very slow. Is there a faster, data.table-friendly alternative?

As a small working example, if I have

```
DT = data.table(a = c(1, 2, 4), b = c(6, 4, 7), 
                c = c(3, 9, 9), d = c(18, 1, -5))
#    a b c  d
# 1: 1 6 3 18
# 2: 2 4 9  1
# 3: 4 7 9 -5
```

what is the most efficient way of computing the row medians?

```
apply(DT, 1, median)
# [1] 4.5 3.0 5.5
```

Comment: Maybe something like `melt(DT[, row := .I], "row")[, median(value), row]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An option is to use the `rowMedians`-function from the [matrixstats](/questions/tagged/matrixstats) package:

```
library(matrixStats)
DT[, med := rowMedians(as.matrix(.SD))][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DT
>    a b c  d med
> 1: 1 6 3 18 4.5
> 2: 2 4 9  1 3.0
> 3: 4 7 9 -5 5.5
> ```

Or with only `data.table`:

```
DT[, med := melt(DT, measure.vars = names(DT))[, r := 1:.N, variable][, median(value), by = r]$V1][]
```